# Jasmine - expect after spy returnValue fails

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with the second `expect` statement after I change a mock service method return value.
I've tried `fakeAsync` and Jasmine's `done` but it still fails, it works only with `setTimeout` which I obviously want to get rid of.

Not working:

```js
// AppComponent.ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AppAuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkAvailableCalculators();
  }

  private checkAvailableCalculators() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.authService.getAvailableCalculators();
    }

    this.authService.getSessionEvents().subscribe(e => {
      if (e === SESSION_EVENTS.login) {
        this.authService.getAvailableCalculators();
      }
    });
  }
}

// AppComponent.spec.ts
    const authServiceMock = {
      getSessionEvents: jasmine.createSpy('getSessionEventsSpy').and.returnValue(of()),
      getAvailableCalculators: jasmine.createSpy('getAvailableCalculators')
    };

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [{provide: AppAuthService, useValue: authServiceMock}],
        declarations: [AppComponent]
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should check for available calculators after login', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

      authServiceMock.getSessionEvents.and.returnValue(of(SESSION_EVENTS.login));
      tick(1000);

      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <=== FAILS
    }));
```

Working:

```js
    it('should check for available calculators after login', () => {
      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

      authServiceMock.getSessionEvents.and.returnValue(of(SESSION_EVENTS.login));

      setTimeout(() => expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).toHaveBeenCalled(), 1000); // <=== PASSES
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of `authServiceMock`?

Comment: I've updated my question with more code

Comment: Can you show the code of your component please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your component code but taking a shot in the dark, try this:

`fixture.whenStable()` waits until the promises have completed.

```
it('should check for available calculators after login', async(done) => {
      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

      authServiceMock.getSessionEvents.and.returnValue(of(SESSION_EVENTS.login));
      await fixture.whenStable();
      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
      done();
    });
```

================================================== Edit ==============

Try this now:

```
// AppComponent.spec.ts
    const authServiceMock = {
      getSessionEvents: jasmine.createSpy('getSessionEventsSpy'),
      getAvailableCalculators: jasmine.createSpy('getAvailableCalculators')
    };
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [{provide: AppAuthService, useValue: authServiceMock}],
        declarations: [AppComponent]
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

   describe('getSessionEvents returning login', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
      // mock getSessionEvents before ngOnInit is called
      authServiceMock.getSessionEvents.and.returnValue(of(SESSION_EVENTS.login));
      fixture.detectChanges(); // !! After this fixture.detectChanges, ngOnInit 
      will be called, no need to call it explicitly.
     });

     it('should check for available calculators after login', () => {
      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
    });
   });

  describe('getSessionEvents returning anything else you want', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      authServiceMock.getSessionEvents.and.returnValue(of('anything else'));
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should not call getAvailableCalculators', () => {
      expect(authServiceMock.getAvailableCalculators).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

The `of` operator could be too late with the implementation you had. The `of` operator doesn't push the value, just provide this value on the next subscription. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I've updated the code in the question with the component.

Comment: I have edited my answer, should hopefully help out.

Comment: The thing is that now you've changed the logic. I wanna check, whether the method is correctly called on subscribe. The code you gave iwould have the same result as if I have put `returnValue(of(SESSION_EVENTS.login))` into `authServiceMock` declaration. I don't think it's a good practice to put it into `beforeEach()`.

Comment: That's correct, you would have had the same results that way. Maybe it's not a good practice depending on what you want. Check out my edit, I have split it into 2 `describe` blocks. One flow where you can test what happens if it returns `SESSION_EVENTS.login` and another flow of it returning something else.